# Hiding category posts from blog section in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to hide an entry from a blog section in wordpress. I have done the typical modification on function.php which is

```
 function exclude_category( $query ) {
   if ( !$query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-114' );
   }
   return $query;
 }
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

And the category is still there. What I am doing wrong?. Thanks in advance

Comment: Code seems to be correct, double-checked category id is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with only `is_home` condition.

```
function exclude_category_home( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', 'YOUR-CAT-ID' );
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_home' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can check the condition is correct for is_home and is_main_query

```
function exclude_category($query) {
    $query->set('cat','-114');
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','exclude_category');
```